# Token validation from backend for Google+ Login on Android Application

Tags: android, node.js, google-plus, google-api-nodejs-client

I am following this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) to validate the token. It is mentioned in the link that for more than 100 requests we should follow below approach.

Using one of the Google API Client Libraries is the recommended way to validate Google ID tokens in a production environment.

The link provides code sample in Java. However I am trying to implement the same in Node.js. But did not find any help on this.

Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: Did you take a look at PassportJS ?